# Return false does not stop form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form that validates, and than logs in the user in PHP. I return false when there is an error, but it does not stop the form from submitting. How can I prevent the form from submitting only when there is an error? I put a `return false` at the bottom but that stopped the whole form from submitting, even if the login was good.

login.js

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {
if (validate({required: "email, password"}) == true) {
    return attemptLogin();
} else {
    return false;
}
});

function attemptLogin() {
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var json = "JSON";
$.ajax({
    url: "/login",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        json: json
    },
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data['message'] != 'undefined') {
            if (data['message'] != 'success') {
                $('#errors').html(data['message']);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

and my PHP

```
if ($validation === true) {
        $user->findByEmail($_POST['email'], array('first_name', 'password', 'id'));
        if (!$user->login($_POST['password'], $user->password, $user->id)) {
            if (isset($_POST['json'])) {
                echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Invalid email or password.'));
                die;
            } else {
                $redirect->to('/login', '<div class="message message-error">Invalid email or password.</div>');
            }
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('message' => 'success'));
            //die;
            $redirect->to('/home', '<div class="message message-success">Hi ' . $user->first_name . ', you have been logged in!</div>');
        }
```

Comment: If you want to stop execution of a loop or module in php then you can use break; This will break the current execution of the php and move on to next part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.preventDefault()` - it will prevent any default browser events;

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  if (validate({required: "email, password"}) == true) attemptLogin();
});
```

Comment: That works for me, however is there any way to continue the PHP so it redirects and flashes a message? If I enter my credentials in it doesn't do that.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this with your code.
You can stay fully ajax and append success message to client wherever you want and then make smth like setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/home' }, 5000) - it will show successfull message to client and redirect him after 5sec to homepage.
Or you can remove ajax stuff and stay with plain form submitting.
Unfortunately i can't see other options for that.

Answer (score 0):

The return false only in if statement. I would like to store a flag that you can return from success function(data). Try this,

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    var flag = true;
    if (data['message'] != 'undefined') {
        if (data['message'] != 'success') {
            $('#errors').html(data['message']);
            flag = false;
            return flag;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```